# Retrieving a Provider from TestingModule when using an interface

Tags: unit-testing, testing, nestjs

I am trying to retrieve a provider from a testing module in NestJS, but cannot resolve that module when providing it out of a module using an interface.

This is what I have so far:

```
const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [AppModule],
}).compile()

...


const fooService = moduleFixture.get<FooService>(FooService) // Nest could not find FooService element
```

When the module exporting the FooService is doing something like this...

```
@Global()
@Module({
  providers: [{ provide: 'IFooService', useClass: FooService }],
  exports: [{ provide: 'IFooService', useClass: FooService }],
})
export class FooModule {}
```

How can I get the FooService instance to be able to call methods directly?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to tell the `get` method to done the same injection token as provided in your code. In this case

```js
const fooService = moduleFixture.get<FooService>('IFooService');
```